# Role manager: dynamic security does not get applied unless the table is as filter in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, ssas, ssas-tabular

I have the next model in SSAS cube:

[image]

(Clients connect to the fact table too)

As seen, a filter in User Access will propagate all the way to the fact…

If I have a dynamic role security with some filter on DAX in User access, will it be applied even if I don’t put/select User access table in the frontend in Power BI??

Per my test, the filter gets applied only if I use a filter from that table, if I don’t use that table the dynamic security does not get applied, why is this??

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the role to filter your security table.
[image: Sample role]

This filters the [_login_id] column of the security table for the user.
[image: Sample security table]

With this filter propagating to related tables, the user **cannot** see any rows hidden by the RLS filter.

There are two important exceptions to this rule though. SSAS admins can see all data regardless of any filters, and in Power BI, if you are an admin, member, or contributor in the workspace, you have access to all the data and RLS does not apply to you. For testing, use the "Test as role" function from the RLS settings in the Power BI Service.